# How to use CSS to center my Heading H1 in a vf Page

Tags: visualforce, css, css3

This is my VF page

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.TestCSSFile}" />

<div class="section1">
<h1>
    H1
</h1>
<br/>
<h2 >
    H2
</h2>
</div>
```

And below is my CSS file

```
h1 {
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
background-color: orange;
}
```

I want my H1 to come in center of page. As you can see in the image below that H1 is not coming in the center of my vf page. How should I do this ?[image: Image showing the present output]

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with Salesforce? This is just a CSS question and belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not really but I was trying this in salesforce visualforce page so asked it here.

Comment: Just an FYI: This IS specific to Salesforce because what works in standard CSS doesn't always apply to VF page stylings. I've had things that work normally in  standard HTML/CSS that will not work in VF pages. This question relates to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text-align: center;
```

will make the text to be centered from their margins. But usually the margins are well around the text so you won't see a big difference.

So you should make the whole div or p tag to be centered using

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 6em
```

The width property sets the width of the div or p tag and the auto value for margin-left and margin-right makes sure the test inside is equally aligned from both margins.

[Reference](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am able to center my h1 tag by putting it in div and then using the following css for the div-:  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 6em;  If I remove width: 6em attribute then I can not see the result. Can you please explain what this attribute in doing and why only 6 value ?

Comment: @TusharArora The rule is you need `display: block`, explicit width, and horizontal margins `auto`.

Comment: If I give width any other than 6em then it is not coming in between. So my question is how you determine that we need to give width of 6em to center it ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to put a `<span>` tag around your H1 tag which should center it on it's own. If it doesn't, just add the following CSS:

```
span + H1{ text-align:center
{
```

If you center the div, you'd be centering everything within the div, so I wouldn't recommend going that route if all you want to center is the H1.

If you specify the class for div you can use an adjacent sibling selector to adjust that particular div that has the H1. See this link for more: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html. It would look something like this:

```
div.section1 + H1 {text-align:center}
```

The above would apply to the div with a class of section1.

Comment: I added a span around my h1 and used the above said css but was not able to center my h1 tag.